# is virtual environment only for development or even for running application

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am using ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10.6 version. My Django application currently works on python 3.7 version and it gives issues in 3.10 version. I want to use virtual environment with python 3.7 version to make application run. If i run the application with Gunicorn for production, will it run 3.7 version of virtual environment of machine version of 3.10?
My project uses Gunicorn, nginx and django.

Comment: Technically they can be used for both. Everything beyond this may be just an opinion.

Comment: my quesion is that will my application work while running in production as it needs python 3.7 not machine versoin 3.10

Comment: That highly depends on your application.

Comment: sorry but i dont get you.

Answer (score 0):

one method is to use pyenv. Using pyenv you can install multiple versions of python. Kindly excuse me if you have already tried this and didnt work for you.